# Swift 3 - Sequence ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I tried to create a custom iterator which returns wrapper `abcContainer` over raw data class `abc`

```
// raw data class
class abc {
    var name : String = "";
    init( _ value : String) {
        name = value;
    }
}

// with container, only "name" is to be visible
class abcContainer {
    private var _abc : abc;
    init( _ obj : abc) {
        _abc = obj;
    }
    // + extra methods here
    func getName() -> String {
       return _abc.name
    }
}
```

The point would be that the dictionary would return instances of `abcContainer` instead of just the plain raw `abc` class.

I wanted to use the sequence protocol to make the conversion automatic, but I was not able to transform the `[String:abc]` into `[String:abcContainer]` automatically like this:

```
// the iterator is implemented just iterating the inner basic dict
// but wrapping the result value as abcContainer
class abcIterator : Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    private var __source : [String:abc]?;
    var index = 0
    var myIterator : DictionaryIterator<String, abc>;

    init(_ ctxArray: [String:abc]) {
        self.__source = ctxArray
        index = 0;
        myIterator = (__source?.makeIterator())!
    }

    func next() -> abcContainer? {
        let nextItem = myIterator.next();
        if(nextItem != nil) {
            return abcContainer((nextItem?.value)!);
        }
        return nil;
    }
}

// this was supposed to be the wrapper over the collection
class abcCollection : Sequence {

    private var __source : [String:abc]?;

    init(_ list: [String:abc]) {
        self.__source = list
    }

    func makeIterator() -> abcIterator {
        return abcIterator(self.__source!);
    }
}
```

I'm probably missing something very basic here. When I try to use the collection like this:

```
    var dict : [String:abc] = [String:abc]();
    dict["abba"] = abc("John Smith");

    for (key,value) in abcCollection(dict) {
        print(key, value.getName());
    }
```

I get error: **Expression type "abcCollection" is ambiguous without more context**

Does anyone have idea how to make it work? What is missing? I have a feeling that this answer has the information I need...

[Swift 2 to 3 Migration for Swift Sequence Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803826/swift-2-to-3-migration-for-swift-sequence-protocol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your original code is that `abcCollection(dict)`
returned a sequence of `abcContainer` objects, and those cannot
be assigned to a `(key, value)` tuple.

You can achieve your goal with

```
class abcCollection : Sequence {

    private var __source : [String:abc]

    init(_ list: [String:abc]) {
        self.__source = list
    }

    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<(AnyObject,abcContainer)> {
        let mapped = self.__source.lazy.map {
            ($0.key as AnyObject, abcContainer($0.value))
        }
        return AnyIterator(mapped.makeIterator())   
    }
}
```

Making `__source` non-optional makes all the (optional) unwrappings
redundant, and `lazy.map { ... }` returns a lazily evaluated
sequence of key/value pairs which is then type-erased.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, perhaps the answer was abcIterator was not necessary, you could have defined the iterator directly just like done in the linked answer like this:

```
class abcCollection : Sequence {

    private var __source : [String:abc]?;

    init(_ list: [String:abc]) {
        self.__source = list
    }

    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<(AnyObject,abcContainer)> {

        var it = self.__source?.makeIterator();
        return AnyIterator {
                let n = it?.next();
                if n == nil { return nil }
                return (n?.key as AnyObject,  abcContainer((n?.value)!))
        }

    }
}
```

After that, the custom collection returned wrapped objects correctly.